# How to display a List<DropDownItem<String>> when using a List.generate method? [flutter]

Tags: flutter

I have a DropDownButton widget -

```
List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> dayValue;
String monthDay;

Widget buildDropdownButtonDay() {
 return new  DropdownButton<String>(
     hint: Text('Choose'),
     onChanged: (String changedValue) {
       monthDay=changedValue;
       setState(() {
         monthDay = changedValue;
//                  print(newValue);
       });
     },
     value: monthDay,
     items: dayValue
 );

}
```

I am using a List.generate method in initState to generate some values to the list `dayValue` like this -

```
 void initState() {
//    numberontroller.text = 1.toString();
   dayValue = List<DropdownMenuItem<String>>.generate(31, (int index) => DropdownMenuItem(child: Text("Day ${index + 1}"),));
   super.initState();
 }
```

When i click on the dropDownButton, the values are listed successfully but when i select a value from this dropdown, the `value` property still displays "Day 1".

Could i get some suggestion on how to set the value property for a DropDownButton widget when we are using a `list.generate` method?

Comment: you did not provide any `value` in `DropdownMenuItem` constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Add the value property in DropdownMenuItem.

dayValue = List<DropdownMenuItem<String>>.generate(
    31,
    (int index) => DropdownMenuItem(
          value: "Day ${index + 1}", //added
          child: Text("Day ${index + 1}"),
        )).toList();
super.initState();
```

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to give dropdownItem a value thas why the issue is occurring just put value parameter while generating a list of Dropdown item

```
dayValue = List<DropdownMenuItem<String>>.generate(31, (int index) => 
DropdownMenuItem(child: Text("Day ${index + 1}"),value:"Day ${index + 1}"));
```